# LOGEVENT logging to WSO2 BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to use LOGEVENT appender to send ERROR logs to BAM for alerts and notification. LOGEVENT is configured in log4j.properties. However, I am facing 2 issues - 
a. Stream name is generated with following convention : _ e.g. log_0_ESB_2014_09_29
b. IP address of ESB is not captured. Cassandra explorer shows "***Non displayable value***"

Please advise, if stream name can be generated as e.g. "ESB_Stream" without date part and IP address can be published with text value.

log4j.properties snippet :
    `log4j.appender.LOGEVENT=org.wso2.carbon.logging.appender.LogEventAppender
     log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.url=tcp://localhost:7611
     log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
     log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.columnList=%T,%S,%A,%d,%c,%p,%m,%H,%I,%Stacktrace
     log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.userName=admin
     log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.password=admin
     log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.processingLimit=1000
     log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.maxTolerableConsecutiveFailure=20
     log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.threshold=WARN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you cannot configure the stream definition name, and it gets created dynamically per tenant per date per instance type. However, we have decided to add this feature for our next releases[1]

Regarding the IP not getting populated issue, we have identified this issue[2] and we have fixed it for our next

Please refer the below public jiras.

[1] - https://wso2.org/browse/CARBON-14851

[2] -  https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14991